# Django signals with ATOMIC_REQUESTS=True

Tags: django

Using Django (and DRF)

If I'm set ATOMIC_REQUESTS=True on the Database config, would this apply for signals as well?

I'm trying to understand if there is a chance our transaction is finished after response

Comment: Django signals don't run asynchronously. If a view triggers a signal and you have `ATOMIC_REQUESTS=True`, then the signal will run synchronously in the same transaction, before the response is returned. If a script triggers a signal, then `ATOMIC_REQUESTS = True`, will have no effect.

Comment: What about sub transaction? I.e if a new transaction is started in the signal?

Comment: If a signal uses `transaction.atomic` and you are already in an atomic block, then Django creates a [savepoint](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/transactions/#savepoints)